# How can I create an additional placeholder attribute using Angular4?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) on a project. Within that project I have a form that is using an [autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) component. Everything is working well - however, I would like to add placeholder text when the user focuses the input element.

Here is my html template:

```
<input type="search" matInput placeholder="My Placeholder"
     aria-label="My Placeholder"
     [matAutocomplete]="mySearch"
     [formControl]="myCtrl"
     (focus)="onInputFocus()"
     [(ngModel)]="myModel">
```

within my `.ts` file, I have this method:

```
public onInputFocus(event: Event): void {
    // do stuff
}
```

Angular Material uses the placeholder attribute and turns that into the label element at runtime. I would like the actual placeholder attribute to say something else other than "My Placeholder".

For example, if a user clicks into the input, "My Placeholder" moves up, and the word "Search" shows as the placeholder text.

I have considered using css to set a background image, or create a custom data attribute. Or within the `.ts` file dynamically create ?? to show placeholder text. Has anyone else run into this issue?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Note: for AngularJS see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63917781/4539906

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, @Will Howell - that got me headed down the right path I think.
What I ended up doing was adding a new attribute "real-placeholder" & manipulating that.

**template.html**

```
<input type="search" real-placeholder="Search" placeholder="My Placeholder"
(focus)="onInputFocus($event)" (blur)="onInputBlur($event)">
```

**component.ts**

```
/**
* Input focus event listener.
* @param {Event} event
*/
public onInputFocus(event: HTMLSelectElement): void {
    const placeholder = event.target.getAttribute('real-placeholder');
    event.target.setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder);
}

/**
* Input blur event listener.
* @param {Event} event
*/
public onInputBlur(event: HTMLSelectElement): void {
    event.target.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
    if (event.target.value !== '') {
        event.target.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:1;');
    }
}
```

**component.scss**

```
[real-placeholder] {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4 ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4 ease-in-out;

    &:focus {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

The above will place the word "Search" in the input area like a traditional html placeholder attribute. I added some nicer css to have the "Search" fade in vs. snap on/off.

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 4):

You can bind to `placeholder` like this

```
<input type="search" matInput [placeholder]="placeholderText">
```

And then in your class,

```
placeholderText = 'My Placeholder';

updatePlaceholderText() {
  this.placeholderText = 'Search';
}
```