# How can I set the opacity of a form element/value on page load using Angular?

Tags: angular

I have an input that I am [dynamically setting/creating the placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042584/how-can-i-create-an-additional-placeholder-attribute-using-angular4).

Everything is working great. The exception is if by default any of the inputs have a value when the page initially loads, the value of the inputs are set to an opacity of 0.

How can I check to see if the input has a value, and if so give the input an opacity of 1?

**template.html**

```
<input type="search" matInput placeholder="My Placeholder" 
    aria-label="My Placeholder" 
    [matAutocomplete]="mySearch" 
    [formControl]="myCtrl 
    (focus)="onInputFocus()" 
    [(ngModel)]="myModel">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) right on the input.

For example:

**template.html**

```
<input type="search" matInput placeholder="My Placeholder" 
    aria-label="My Placeholder" 
    [matAutocomplete]="mySearch" 
    [formControl]="myCtrl 
    (focus)="onInputFocus()" 
    [ngStyle]="{'opacity':myAttribute.myVaue !== '' ? '1' : '' }" // Set the default opacity
    [(ngModel)]="myModel">
```