# Generate input element dynamically with placeholder & ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to generate inputs elements dynamically in angular 2+.
I've placeholder title array and value arrays as below:

In my component I have two map as below where key is same for both which maps the value to title:

```
const placeholderMap = {fullName: 'Name', value: 'Product Value'};
cont valueMap = {fullName: 'Alpha Product', value: '2234.234'};
```

I want to use the map above and generate inputs elements like below dynamically:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Name" value='Alpha Product'/>
<input matInput placeholder="Product Value" value='2234.234'/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can us an `*ngFor` with an array of the key names to loop through and bind all of the values in your map.

```html
<input matInput *ngFor="let key of ['fullName', 'value']"
  [placeholder]="placeholderMap[key]"
  [(ngModel)]="valueMap[key]" />
```

Instead of specifying all the key names explicitly in the template you could also get a reference to all the keys in your component like so:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.inputKeys = Object.keys(this.valueMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For AngularJS** use `ng-attr-placeholder` instead of `[placeholder]`.

For example, I'm using different placeholders for different search terms using

```
 ng-attr-placeholder="{{isAdvanceSearch ? setPlaceholder(searchOption) : 'John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123'}}"
```

Here on the basis of `isAdvanceSearch` variable, I'm setting different placeholders in `setPlaceholder` method.

`setPlaceholder` method returns the placeholder to set in the input field.

```
$scope.setPlaceholder = function(searchOption) {
     if (searchOption === "foo") {
          return "Search by foo… e.g. foo1";
     } else if (searchOption === "bar") {
          return "Search by bar… e.g. bar123";
     } else {
          return "John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123";
     }
};
```

Note: `John Smith, 08/23/1970, 123` is the default placeholder.
Don't forget to wrap the expression in the `{{}}` brackets.