# "Placeholder" attribute in an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Dynamic text instead of static text in place holder attribute,which comes from a key value pair in localization(.json file), i am working on Aurelia framework
I was implementing Localization in a Aurelia project, in one of the files, i was looking for "placeholder" attribute to sport dynamic value rather than static value, if some one could help me with this
Thanks! in advance

Heading_Text is a "key value" pair name picked up from some.json for the particular language, the application is loaded in

Comment: <input [plcaeholder]="dynamicVal">?

Comment: please add some code to the question

Comment: <input id="search" type="text"  value.bind="filters[0].value" placeholder.ref="Heading_Text" i18n="Heading_Text" keyup.trigger=somefunc()/>

Comment: `<input placeholder = "{{yourVariable}}" >`

Comment: it doesn't work, loads the expression as is

Comment: <input [plcaeholder]="dynamicVal">?...this doesn't work too :(

Comment: please try to provide a minimal, reproducible code snippet for others to see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the input placeholder value using Javascript, which will be easier when you need dynamic value

```
input.attr("placeholder", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue

```
<input [placeholder]="variableName" type= "text" [(ngModel)]="modelName"/>
```

**component.ts**

```
variableName = 'placeholder For modelName'
```

here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5juh3?file=src/app/app.component.html)

and for more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50765744/generate-input-element-dynamically-with-placeholder-ngmodel)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the placeholder value in component and it should work fine.

```
 <input [attr.placeholder]="componentVariable" [(ngModel)]="modelName"/>
```

Or

```
 <input [placeholder]="componentVariable" [(ngModel)]="modelName"/>
```

As soon as your `componentVariable` gets a value on component load or when the data is received in component, the input field placeholder should be able to display the text as needed.